# block/drop Socket in ebpf hooking at syscall tracepoint 'sys_enter_connect' and 'sys_enter_bind' for any specific Process

Tags: ebpf, xdp-bpf

`Hi All,

I am trying to block/drop socket connection at trace point hooking at "sys_enter_connect" and "sys_enter_bind" for some specific process. my code snippet below:

```c
SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_connect")
int tracepoint_connect_enter(struct enter_connect_format *ctx){
    // check for PID and process name, then if condition matches, block the socket connection 
    return -1; // to block the socket connection
    // else
    return 0;
}

// I do the same for bind also

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_bind")
int tracepoint_bind_enter(struct enter_bind_format *ctx)
{
    // same as above
    return -1;
    // else
    return 0;
}
```

But, I am not able to get the desired result; still, network packet send and receive captured for that specific process. Any input will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use tracepoint to block anything. For your case, you can try using `bpf_override_return`(with kprobe), lsm, TC, XDP, or cgroup-related program/attach types.